# Проверка кодировки и конвертация в нужную

Tags: функции, php, utf-8

Есть небольшой класс проверки приходящих данных, есть проблема в кодировках, с некоторых сайтов кодировки приходят правильные, а с некоторых неправильные. Как сделать определение и конвертацию в нужную кодировку?

```
function checkrequest($textrequest) {
// Удираем лишние пробелы
//$textrequest = trim($textrequest);
// Производим конвертацию в необходимую кодировку (нужно если у Вас проект использует кодировку отличную от UTF-8)
$textrequest = iconv("UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1251", $textrequest);
// Фиксируем атаки
if (preg_match("/script|http|<|>|<|>|SELECT|UNION|UPDATE|exe|exec|INSERT|tmp/i",$textrequest)) {
writelog('hack', date("y.m.d H:m:s")."\t".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\t".$textrequest);
$textrequest = '';
}
// Очищаем опасные запросы
if (preg_match("/[^(\w)|(А-Яа-я-&=.,@():;)|(\s)]/",$textrequest)) {
$textrequest = '';
}
// Если не число, то экранируем ковычки
if (!is_numeric($textrequest)) {
$textrequest = mysql_real_escape_string($textrequest);
}

return $textrequest;
}
```

Comment: @Alexander Sizintsev, проще всего будет тянуть курлом декодер лебедева. Хотя можно попробовать угадать символы за счет частоты их использования (для этого даже есть хорошее слово, но я его забыл) или проверить наличие характерных для неправильной кодировки символов.

Comment: Явно плохое решение и долгое для API.